# Change the buttons on the angular material Nav-bar based on page

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular, angular-material

I have my navbar deigned using angular material in my app.component.html page.
It initially contains LOGIN button, but when  user is logged in successfully, login button should be hidden

**Current approach:**
I am disabling the login button based on boolean attribute in localstorage, but in this case, login button is not disabled until i refresh my page.

My Navbar is created as shared component, So Is there a way i can add new button based on page and data is updated without refreshing the page?

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Navbar.component.html:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z">
  <span><mat-icon>post_add</mat-icon> ED-Planner</span>
  <div class="spacer">  </div>
    <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/user']">Home</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" [routerLink]="['/user/signup']">Signup</button>

</mat-toolbar>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, user data usually is stored in localstorage.
If you create a service for example, you can store it there too, and provide it (make sure its providedIn root, so there will be only 1 instance).

After you log in your user, you can store it's data in the service, or localstorage (please pay attention for security), you can do something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf=isLoggedIn; else loggedOut>
 //Your content when the user is logged in), few else buttons for example profile or something
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loggedOut>
//your login section
</ng-template>
```